# How to randomly generate a positive semidefinite matrix subject to Loewner constraint?

Tags: random-generation, covariance-matrix, correlation-matrix

For real, symmetric, positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$, let $\leq_L$ denote the [Loewner partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order): $A \leq_L B$ iff $B-A$ is positive semidefinite.  Suppose $A$ and $B$ are fixed PSD matrices. Is there a method to randomly generate PSD matrices from the region $\{X | A \leq_L X \leq_L B\}$? Better yet, is there a way to uniformly sample matrices from this region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb S_n$ be the set of $n \times n$ symmetric matrices. Given positive semidefinite matrices $\mathrm A, \mathrm B \in \mathbb S_n$, the following (convex) set

$$\{ \mathrm X \in \mathbb S_n \mid \mathrm A \preceq \mathrm X \preceq \mathrm B \}$$

is a [spectrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrahedron). To sample from spectrahedra, take a look at Narayanan's paper [0] and the references therein.

---

[0] Hariharan Narayanan, [Randomized Interior Point methods for Sampling and Optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3950), arXiv:0911.3950.